# How do you combine multiple com.twitter.util.Awaitable's with Future.select semantics?

Tags: scala, finagle, twitter-util

In a service, I have a main method that starts a `com.twitter.finagle.ListeningServer` and also creates a custom "channel" returning a `com.twitter.util.Future` that never completes (unless there is an error). Both are actually `com.twitter.util.Awaitable` instances and I want to shut down my service if either of them completes.

If both were `com.twitter.util.Future`s I could use `Future.select` to select the first future that complete, so right now I am converting the `com.twitter.finagle.ListeningServer` into a `com.twitter.util.Future` using `pool { Await.result(listeningServer) }`.

Is there a better way to solve my problem?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you prefer `com.twitter.util.Future` to `scala.concurrent.Future`?

Comment: I don't prefer it but if you work with Finagle it's build around `com.twitter.util.Future`